# Similarity between electric displacement and electric field in a linear homogeneous dielectric

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, vector-fields

Griffiths says

> ...if the space is entirely filled with a homogeneous $^{10}$ linear dielectric: in this rather special circumstance we have
> $$
> \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{D}=\rho_{f} \quad \text { and } \quad \boldsymbol{\nabla}\times \mathbf{D}=0
> $$  so
> $D$ can be found from the free charge just as though the dielectric were not there
> $$
> \mathbf{D}=\epsilon_{0} \mathbf{E}_{\text {vac}}
> $$.
> The explanation given to the same question on this site is that, this is because of the similarity between the below equations $$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{D}=\rho_{\rm f} \:\:\:{\rm and}\:\:\: \boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{D}=0$$
> $$\updownarrow$$
> $$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}_{\rm vac}=\frac{\rho_{\rm f}}{\epsilon_{0}} \:\:\:{\rm and}\:\:\: \boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{E}_{\rm vac}=0$$

However how can one deduce from this similarity the relation between $D$ and $E$ knowing that two different functions can have the same divergence and curl,( like two constant functions)?